# createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance not called

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, core-data-migration

I am trying to do custom migration for CoreData entry. I need to change name and type for an attribute.

So I added new datamodel and mappingmodel. For example, I have myData(String) in old model and I need CarDate(Date) in new model.
I added row: CarDate => $source.myData to the *.xcmappingmodel file and created class:

```
@implementation RemindersMigration

- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance
                                  entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping
                                        manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager
                                          error:(NSError **)error {

NSManagedObject *newObject =
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[mapping destinationEntityName]
                              inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];

NSString *dateString = [sInstance valueForKey:@"myData"];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = ...;

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

[newObject setValue:date forKey:@"CarDate"];

[manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:newObject forEntityMapping:mapping];

return YES;
```

}

I tested migration with simulator, so I switched to old version with Git, added new entry, switched to new version. In CarDate I have nil.
Please point me where I am wrong?

Comment: I know this is old, but.... Did you set the class name of the custom policy in the mapping model?

Answer (score 2):

In the Mapping Model Editor, select the Entity Mapping, open the Utilities pane (right side), and select the Mapping Model Inspector (alt+command+3).

Enter the name of your NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass (in your case RemindersMigration) in the Custom Policy field.

[image]